# Ratios of shares

Tags: arithmetic

I already asked this question yesterday.
I received an answer which was helpful, but I feel like something is still missing.
Also I received a -1 and the question get closed for some reason :(
So here I come again ...

I have to share $100,000$ points to $400$ players but $10$ of them (the highest scores) must receive $25$% more points than the others.

Here is my first post: [Unequal sharing percentage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302656/unequal-sharing-percentage)

1. I tried many "naives" approaches which all lead me to wrong results, I always end with gaps.
2. I understand now that what I need is called: "Ratio of shares" and that ratio of shares must be $(4:5)$ but i'm certain the answer I received does not take the $25$% bonus rule for the $10$ best players in count.
3. I understand that the total amount to share ($100,000$ in this example) may not be perfectly divisible by the given results, but that's the way it works. The players do their game together, they generate a certain amount of points together which then must be equally shared following the $+25$% rule for the $10$ first. That won't be a big deal if few hundred points are not given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $x$ is the amount that the 390 players get then the 10 first will get $1.25x$. You can then say that you want:

$100000 = 10\cdot 1.25 x + 390\cdot x$

solving for $x$ you get $x = 248.44$ and when rounding down you get $x=248$. This is what the 390 players get. The remaining 10 get $1.25x$ so they get $310$ (luckily this is an integer). In total you will have distributed 99820 shares which leaves 180 shares that can not be distributed (but you said that was ok)